# How to get Open Graph meta data from Instagram url using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, instagram, facebook-opengraph

### Problem:

Similar to other social media sites, I **want to show preview of Instagram links** in my website. But when I cannot cannot get the meta tags from the webpage as the html shown when the page accessed from the browser is different from that when accessed through [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios). I cannot get the [Open Graph tags](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-open-graph-and-how-can-i-use-it-for-my-website/) in Instagram pages.

### What I have tried

packages used: [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) and [`jssoup`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jssoup) 
post url used in example below: https://www.instagram.com/p/Cg39m-KjfC8/

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;
var JSSoup = require('jssoup').default

const fetchOgDatafromInsta = async (postid) => {
  // let's consider this url for example
  page = await axios.get(`https://www.instagram.com/p/Cg39m-KjfC8/`, {
    headers: {
      "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
      "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.81 Safari/537.36",
      "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "accept-language": "en-US;q=0.7",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
      "sec-fetch-site": "none",
      "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
      "sec-gpc": 1,
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": 1
    },
  })
  var soup = new JSSoup(page.data, false)
  const allMeta = soup.findAll(('meta'))
  allMeta.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.attrs);
  });
}
```

With or without the header the result is same. Tags like `<meta property="og:image"/>` are absent.
[image]

**Is there any other way to get the meta tag data? Most Social media paltforms can do this!!!**

Please help!!!

Any suggestion accepted gratefully. Thanks in advance.